# How to convert user-friendly infix math code to Clojure code?

Tags: parsing, clojure, infix-notation

I want user to be able to input like this:

```
5+6*t+sin(2*t)
```

, so it will get converted to this:

```
(+ 5 (* 6 t) (sin (* 2 t)))
```

, so I can eval it to some function that will be JITted and executed efficiently later.

Are there already available libraries (with operator priorities) that works in up-to-date Clojure already?

Comment: I'm sure there are dozen or so examples for that in antlr that you can pick up and use with a little modification.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the Incanter package include a [module for doing infix math](http://data-sorcery.org/2010/05/14/infix-math/)

```
user> ($= 7 + 8 - 2 * 6 / 2)
9
```

and others have [written packages](https://github.com/tristan/clojure-infix).

Comment: Requiring spaces seems to be a bit restricting. And I expect string as input (here I also need to mess with `read`).

Comment: I tried clojuire-infix, but it seems to be abandonware (that is why I included "works in up-to-date Clojure" clause).

Comment: @Vi. Can't you just automatically parse the string to add a space around all the operators?